# Синий favicon сайта ru.stackoverflow.com

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, дизайн, favicon

С недавних пор favicon сайта ru.stackoverflow.com стал белым на синем фоне. Это так и задумано?

Наблюдаю в браузерах Firefox, Google Chrome и Яндекс.Браузер.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Бессмысленный и беспощадный Russian Reversal. В Советской России favicon непрозрачен. Верните уже нормальный прозрачный фон как было раньше.

Comment: Согласен, раньше было лучше.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/EmZhKoF.png Вот еще в коллекцию уродств. Даже моя собака нарисовала бы его лучше, правда.

Comment: и надпись "на русском" кривая - буквы сс на пиксель выше, р - на пиксель ниже

Comment: @PashaPash, если приблизить и померять по пикселям, то все ровно. Хотя визуально надпись "на русском" действительно выглядит как-то кривовато.

Comment: @insolor неровно на один пиксель. вот приближенный вариант с чертой - http://imgur.com/RzppasS

Comment: @PashaPash, таки да, соглашусь. Открыл оригинал в svg, который отдает сайт (http://cdn.sstatic.net/ru/img/sprites.svg?v=4fd96dc0596e), там вот такое безобразие: http://i.imgur.com/McTQVl2.png

Comment: Хотя и надпись stackoverflow - тоже эдакий "ад для перфекциониста":
http://i.imgur.com/OfJuc5w.png

Comment: У японцев красный фавикон, а у португальцев - зеленый.

Comment: Про ребрендинг в соседней теме: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1312/

Comment: [Cинее на оранжевом](http://i.imgur.com/AoVli7R.png)

Comment: Лично мне новая иконка сайта нравится. В любом случае, добавил в базу дефектов упомянутую вами проблему. Как только команда дизайнеров примет решение (обновить или оставить как есть), я обязательно отпишусь.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, хуже то, что я к ней начинаю привыкать ) Я первоначально вообще подумал, что это инвентированная старая иконка. Буду ждать ответа дизайнеров )

Comment: @igumnov зачем такие грубости про уродства и собак?

Comment: @Regent Ах это либеральное двоемыслие. Вам разве не кажется этот логотип грубой, неудачной, политизированной шуткой еще и вдобавок художественно довольно уродливой? Какая шутка, такой и ответ, ничего личного.

Comment: @igumnov нет, не кажется: логотип как логотип. Вкусы у всех разные. Nicolas'у иконка нравится, например. Было бы здорово уважать чужие вкус и труд, а критиковать - конструктивно.

Comment: @Regent Да при чем тут вкусы и труд? С таким же успехом можно было не перекатываясь на новый движок создать еще один сайт для англоговорящих пользователей и написать на логотипе "Пиндосы". Там бы тоже наверняка появился юзер, который утверждал что новый логотип ОК и  надо уважать чужой труд. P.S. Тема начинает скатываться и я не намерен её продолжать. Относитесь к логотипу как хотите, это Ваше дело а не мое, а я просто указал причину по которой не считаю свой комментарий грубым, как вы сами и просили.

Comment: @igumnov для [меты](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/) прозрачный, кстати.

Answer (score 6):

Если кто-то хочет осмысленных иконок, а не подчёркиваний и негативов разных цветов, то я делал предложение на MSE:

[**Less confusing icons for localized Stack Overflow sites**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252622/less-confusing-icons-for-localized-stack-overflow-sites)

Пример: [image]

Если предложение нравится, можете проголосовать. Авось заметят...

Comment: Иконки изменились, но актуальность вопроса не пострадала.

Answer (score 5):

1. Мое мнение - новый favicon ужасен. Возможно, мое мнение ни на что не повлияет, но первоначальный вариант был намного лучше.
2. Я считаю, что favicon "неанглийского" раздела SO не обязан отличаться от favicon основного SO, т.к. в первую очередь я смотрю на содержимое страницы и на основной логотип, и у меня никогда не возникает сомнения, нахожусь я в русском разделе или в английском.
3. Если дело дойдет до смены цветов логотипа RU.SO, то опять же, текущие цвета (чёрный-оранжевый-серый) меня вполне устраивают, ничего менять не нужно. Надпись "на русском" под "stackoverflow" достаточно явно намекает на языковую принадлежность раздела.

Answer (score -5):

Вот еще 32x32, но я плохо рисую: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но у нас *русскоязычный*, а не *российский* SO.